# why do I have to double tap command + space to open spotlight?

Tags: keyboard, spotlight

Since I installed High Sierra I *sometimes* have to double tap <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to open spotlight search bar. This problem is weird because it happens randomly. Say I just double tapped <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, it won't happen again for a couple minutes.

I haven't setup any shortcut nor I use any app that steals this shortcut. I have no idea what is going on and it is really boring, cause sometimes I'm in a text editor, tap <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, nothing happens but as I'm used to it, I start type right away and mess up my code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem. Apparently, Siri is waiting to see if it's being called. In the Siri preferences, there's a setting for Keyboard Shortcut which is set to **Hold Command Space** by default. So sometimes you might be pressing a little longer but not long enough for Siri to kick in.

Change this setting to **Press Fn (Function) Space** as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Change Siri Keyboard Shortcut]

Comment: I'll be forever grateful for this and I'll tell my grandchildren the story of a man who once saved my life!

Comment: I was ready to reload my MacBook Air since I assumed this was just a performance issue.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Look in SystemPreferences->Keyboard->Shortcut select Spotlight (while Textedit open) if there is a message that CMD+Space is "used by another app".

Comment: nope, this is what I have: https://i.imgur.com/c8F5fOR.png